# Why does my code not run when I type in "Set Code"?

Tags: c#, console, console-application, readline, console.readline

I have this code here:

```
    string code1 = null;
    Console.Write("Username: " + Environment.UserName.ToString() + ">");
    if (Console.ReadLine() == "info")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Info:");
    }
    else if (Console.ReadLine() == "Set Code")
    {
        if (code1 == null)
        {
            Console.Write("TEST");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'Set Code' is not known as a command \nEnter 'info' to view all commands");
            Console.Write("Username: " + Environment.UserName.ToString() + ">");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        string temp = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("'" + temp + "' is not known as a command \nEnter 'info' to view all commands");
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

When I type in "Set Code" it does nothing, and then when I type in something like info, it goes to `string temp = Console.ReadLine();` but then it does not run `Console.WriteLine("'" + temp + "' is not known as a command \nEnter 'info' to view all commands");`

Why does it not run anything else when I put in that code?
I debugged it step by step, and it just like breaks there.

Answer (score 3):

Because "Set Code" is expected as an input only on the 2nd input and if only the first input  was not "info"...

try this:

```
string code1 = null;
while(true)
{
    Console.Write("Username: " + Environment.UserName.ToString() + ">");
    string line = Console.ReadLine();
    if (line == "info")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Info:");
    }
    else if (line == "Set Code")
    {
        if (code1 == null)
        {
            Console.Write("TEST");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'Set Code' is not known as a command \nEnter 'info' to view all commands");
            Console.Write("Username: " + Environment.UserName.ToString() + ">");
        }
    }
    else if (line == "quit")
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("'" + line + "' is not known as a command \nEnter 'info' to view all commands");
    }
}
```

You only need to do ReadLine() once, to get a line from the user, then you make your comparison on that line, not on a new ReadLine() since every ReadLine() you make yields a new, different input from the user.

Comment: Just one more ReadLine to remove and you have it right.

Comment: Thanks, missed that one at the else :)

Comment: @Steve What do you mean?

Comment: there was another 'ReadLine()' at the last else going into a 'temp' variable... I removed it as @Steve remarked and replaced the temp with 'line'

Comment: When I use that code that you posted @eyalsn, then what happens, it that if I try something like null, then it will still not run the else code. The only thing that happens, is that temp is console.readLine and nothing else

Comment: There is not need to temp = Console.ReadLine(), the invalid command had been already written in the line = Console.ReadLine()

Comment: @eyalsn I see now, let me try that. Thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: That fixed that one problem, but now I can type something in once, and then if I try to type something in again, then it just closes it. What is wrong?

Comment: Then you should run that code in a while loop, and I edited the code...
'quit' breaks the while loop and exits

Comment: @JackNelson Was happy to help, If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Because each time you call `Console.ReadLine()` you are getting a new input.If you write `"Set Code"` your first if statement will be passed but then in your else if statement you are calling `Console.ReadLine` again, and  `else if` will check your new input after you type,not the first one.Instead get input first and store into a variable then use that variable inside of your if - elseif statements:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
if (input == "info")
```